# How to reload tasks using the Qlik CLI for Unix?

Tags: unix, ssh, qliksense, airflow-webserver

I'm trying to reload tasks in qlik enterprise using an external unix server through SSH. There is not any documentation about unix commands for running it. Does anyone knows how to run it? I need before the auth and after to run the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use my module https://pypi.org/project/qlikflow/ for apache airflow , maybe it's a little out of date and you need to make some edits